# failed to apt-get install ros-kinetic-geodesy

Tags: ros

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python-pyproj ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs ros-kinetic-unique-id ros-kinetic-uuid-msgs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pyproj ros-kinetic-geodesy ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs ros-kinetic-unique-id
  ros-kinetic-uuid-msgs
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 95 not upgraded.
Need to get 112 kB/153 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,748 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-uuid-msgs amd64 1.0.5-0xenial-20180824-101255-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 2402:f000:1:408:8100::1 80]
Err:2 http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs amd64 0.5.2-0xenial-20181107-010739-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 2402:f000:1:408:8100::1 80]
Err:3 http:/
/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-unique-id amd64 1.0.5-0xenial-20190320-125240-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 2402:f000:1:408:8100::1 80]
Err:4 http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-geodesy amd64 0.5.2-0xenial-20190320-160038-0800
  404  Not Found [IP: 2402:f000:1:408:8100::1 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-uuid-msgs/ros-kinetic-uuid-msgs_1.0.5-0xenial-20180824-101255-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2402:f000:1:408:8100::1 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs/ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs_0.5.2-0xenial-20181107-010739-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2402:f000:1:408:8100::1 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-unique-id/ros-kinetic-unique-id_1.0.5-0xenial-20190320-125240-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2402:f000:1:408:8100::1 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-geodesy/ros-kinetic-geodesy_0.5.2-0xenial-20190320-160038-0800_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2402:f000:1:408:8100::1 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Run `apt-get update` first.  Sounds like things're out of date.

Comment: After running "apt-get update" I still get the same output.

Comment: Test those mirror URLs, or simply try a different mirror.

Comment: Solved by downloading the Debian package here-https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-geodesy/

Comment: I would use a different mirror since it seems the data your system sees in that repo is out of date with with what is in it.